# Django Unable to Import Settings Module

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to host a simple Django app on AWS.

I can run it via the public DNS and runserver, but I can't seem to get the environment URL working.

I checked the log and it says "ImportError: Could not import settings 'AppName.settings'"

I've tried adding sys.path.append('/opt/python/current/app/ProjectName/AppName') to the WSGI file, but when I try to print out the sys.paths, it is not listed.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import till project name like

`sys.path.append('/opt/python/current/app/ProjectName')`

That will ensure project directory is in pythonpath and you can import AppName from there.